# LD_PRELOAD loaded event

Tags: linux

I writed my LD_PRELOAD module and i want to add some initialization code before my overrided functions work. Maybe LD_PRELOAD have any loaded event or something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about a "loaded" event, however if you're using `gcc`, you may find the `constructor` attribute useful. Take for example:

**testlib.c**:
    #include

```
void testing(void) __attribute__((constructor));

void testing(void)
{
  printf("It worked!\n");
}
```

**hworld.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -o hworld hworld.c
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o testlib.so testlib.c
$ export LD_PRELOAD=./testlib.so
$ ./hworld 
It worked!
Hello world!
```

The [constructor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) attribute means that the function should be executed before `main()`.  Alternatively, if you're using C++, you could create a static global instance of a class whose constructor does the initialization, which would achieve the same effect as using `constructor`.

Comment: Thanks! But i noticed that this constructor called more that one time, can you help how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @user1262425 can you update with an example of where you see it called more than once? Afaik it ought to only be called once, before `main()` runs.